# Passing 2D array and vector of string as argument to function

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments

I have written two function in which I am passing vector of string to a particular function (PrintStringVector) just to print content and in second function, passing the array of pointers to print the content.The first function is working fine but second one is giving error which is below the my code.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int n;

void PrintStringVector(vector<string> & v){


    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){ cout<<v[i]<<endl;}

}


void PrintStringArray(const char *arr[n]){

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ cout<<arr[i]<<endl;}



}

int main() {

    vector<string>  vec;                    
    cin>>n;
    const char *arr[n];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        string str;
        cin>>str; 
        vec.push_back(str);
        arr[i]=str.c_str();
    }

    PrintStringVector(vec);
    PrintStringArray(arr);


    return 0;
}
```

ERRORS:

```
        vinod@vinod-Inspiron-3537:~/Documents/hackerrank$ g++       passing_vector_of_string_or_passing_2d_array.cpp 
        passing_vector_of_string_or_passing_2d_array.cpp:17:35: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘arr’
        void PrintStringArray(const char* arr[n]){
                                           ^
        passing_vector_of_string_or_passing_2d_array.cpp: In function ‘void PrintStringArray(const char*)’:
        passing_vector_of_string_or_passing_2d_array.cpp:19:33: error: ‘arr’ was not declared in this scope
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ cout<<arr[i]<<endl;}
                                         ^
        passing_vector_of_string_or_passing_2d_array.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
        passing_vector_of_string_or_passing_2d_array.cpp:40:25: error: cannot convert ‘const char**’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void PrintStringArray(const char*)’
        PrintStringArray(arr);
```

Comment: Another problem with your code is that you are storing the address of memory managed by a local variable that goes out of scope `str` when you do `arr[i] = str.c_str();` This will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Since I had not better solution to assign string str to character pointer.I think c_str() convert c++ string to c string (made of char array).

Comment: `c_str()` returns back a pointer that is C compatible, but this pointer is only valid while the `std::string` object that returned it exists. You are using it after this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const char *arr[n]
```

This is not a valid declaration (unless `n` is a constant expression). C++ has no variable length arrays.

"But it works for me inside `main`!'

That's because g++ implements an extension to C++. This extension does not seem compatible with C variable-length arrays, and is generally buggy. Don't use it.

"But how can I have comparable functionality?"

Use `std::vector`. Do not use pointers, `new[]` and `delete[]` unless you know extremely well why you need these low-level primitives.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you cannot have VLA (variable length arrays). Since the size of the array `arr` is only known at runtime you cannot use it as a size of a fixed size array. You should use `new` to allocate it. E.g.

```
const char **arr = new const char*[n];
```

Also modify the function signature like this

```
void PrintStringArray(const char *arr[]){
```

or like this

```
void PrintStringArray(const char **arr){
```

Finally remember to delete `arr` once you are finished with it.

```
delete[] arr;
```

Comment: No. You shouldn't use `new` to allocate arrays. (You *can*, but *should not*). You should use `std::vector`.